# Oracle Cloud always free tier. Am I eligible?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is there somewhere on my account dashboard, profile, etc that will state whether I am eligible for Oracle Always Free tier?

Answer (score 3):

The majority of OCI accounts are Free Tier eligible, but there is not a flag/attribute displayed in the Console to communicate eligibility.

Always Free resources will show-up as options in your Tenancy's Home Region, presuming you're eligible. You'll see visual breadcrumbs saying 'Always Free Eligible' for choices that are dependencies of Always Free resource creation.

If you're in your home region, and not seeing Always Free options in resource creation flows, you're likely in the minority of accounts without access.  You can create a new account that supports Always Free via oracle.com/cloud/free.

Answer (score 2):

One way to check is:

1. Go to Administration > Tenancy Details.
2. Scroll down to Service Limits.
3. Expand the Compute node and search for "VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro". You should find your limit and usage counts. Should say "2" for limits, under your home region.
4. Expand the Database node and search for "Always Free Autonomous Database Instance Count". You should also see "2" for limits under your home region.

If your account was created before the OOW19 announcements and you're not on the "Monthly Flex" plan, then chances are, your account is not eligible. Talk to your sales rep for the best path to get the Always Free resources.

Comment: I got message from Oracle . It is always free if you are using your account active. It says just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Try and create an autonomous data warehouse or autonomous transaction processing database.

On the first page scroll down a page or so till you get to the 'configure the database' section and if you can select the option 'always free' your account is eligible.

See picture:
[image]